Confusion about reversibility of a carnot engine
I recently posted a question about entropy and the conversation changed topic to bring up an interesting question. @Chemomechanics explained that for a transformation to be reversible it is needed that the (say 2) objects are constantly in thermal equilibrium, hence the need of an infinite number of thermal reservoirs, each one at a (infinitesimally) different temperature.

Even infinitesimally slow heat transfer between objects at two different temperatures is irreversible.

Given this assumption, I wonder how is it possible for the Carnot - cycle to be reversible since it operates between two temperatures and there is no need of an infinite number of thermal reservoirs.

What he is saying is that if you needed to transfer heat at a continuum of temperatures, then you will also need an infinite number of thermal reservoirs. The Carnot cycle only uses two thermal reservoirs and only ever transfers heat when in contact with them. In the other parts of the cycle, there is no heat transfer, and so it does not require an infinite number of thermal reservoirs. It just needs the cycle to happen infinitely slowly.

In the Carnot cycle, the temperature of each reservoir differs only infinitesimally from the temperature of the working fluid (gas) so that the heat transfer takes place reversibly.

So there are only 2 resevoirs of almost the same temperature? Doesn't this make the efficiency $\eta = 0$ ?

The reservoirs are out at the same temperature. First, the working fluid receives heat from the high temperature reservoir. And later in the process, the working fluid gives up heat to the cold temperature reservoir

I don't understand: are the two resevoirs at the same temperature? And if they are how can $\eta \neq 0$? But if the reverois aren't at the same temperature doesn't this make the carnot cycle irreversible?

@Lorenzo - they are not at the same temperature. The piston chamber is not in thermal contact with both reservoirs at all times, but alternates (or I guess, ping-pongs) between being in contact with one, none, or the other. The gas starts out hot, flowed by isothermal expansion, but after that phase, it continues to expand, without being in thermal contact with either reservoir, and the temperature drops to nearly the temperature of the cold reservoir. (I suppose Chet Miller's reply got auto corrected or something).

The Carnot operates reversibly between only two reservoirs by using adiabatic expansion and compression steps—not heat transfer—to swing between the temperature extremes.
During the isothermal steps, heat transfer occurs either from the hot reservoir or to the cold reservoir over an infinitesimal temperature difference, which is reversible.
During all the steps, expansion or compression also occurs infinitesimally slowly, which is also reversible.
Note carefully the difference between changing an object’s temperature via heating or via work. The former conceptually requires successive contact with an infinite number of thermal reservoirs to be reversible. The latter can span the same temperature range—thus allowing interaction with only two reservoirs, if desired, as in the Carnot engine—but requires the work to be quasistatic (and adiabatic) to be reversible.

Oh so when the system is in contact with the cold resevoir they almost have the same temperature, same thing for the hot resevoir, is this correct? And the infinitesimal heat transferred is needed for the cycle to continue I guess. But since $W = Q_\text{H} - Q_\text{C}$ doesn't this mean the system won't do any work? Or is $Q_\text{H}$, even if infinitesimally, bigger than $Q_\text{C}$? Sorry for all the questions btw

$Q_\mathrm{H}$ and $Q_\mathrm{C}$ are finite and different; $Q_\mathrm{H}>Q_\mathrm{C}$ corresponds to a Carnot heat engine and $Q_\mathrm{H}<Q_\mathrm{C}$ to a Carnot heat pump. The finite heat transfer steps are idealized as the extremes of a very small temperature difference driving a very small heat flux, for a very long amount of time, yielding finite $Q$.


for a transformation to be revesible it is needed that the (say 2) objects are constantly in thermal equilibrium

This is related to reversible exchange of heat. In order to two systems to exchange heat reversibly, they should be at the same temperature. The idea is simple: if they are not in the same temperature, say, one is with higher temperature $T_1 > T_2$. The heat could be transfered for $1\to 2$ in a spontaneous process, but not $2\to 1$, so it can't be reversible.
In Carnot cycle, the hear transfer happens during the isothermal processes, and the only non-isothermic process are adiabatic, i.e., there are no exchange of heat.
Irreversible exchange of heat is related to increase of global entropy. During reversible process, the entropy of the system increase, but the entropy of the Universe does not change.
It seems that you are having some difficulties to analyze the Carnot cycle. I would recommend you to read some solid reference about it. You could start through the Feynman lectures.

Thank you for your answers. So If the transformation is reversible I shouldn't be able to tell in which direction the heat flew?

You should be able, by analysing other aspects of the system. For example, during the isothermal expansion, the system in expansion realize work, so it receives heat, in order to not vary its internal energy

Reversible doesn't mean symmetrical process. It means that you could run the process reversed without violating the second law.

Oh okay thanks for the clarification and for the suggestion!
